# Fedora dnf system-upgrade: too many skipped packages?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, dnf

I am sure this is a known issue, but I couldn't find the precise answer. Sorry if this is the case.

I am trying a `dnf system-upgrade` from my fully updated Fedora 23 to Fedora 26 (or 25, or 24). When I try

`dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=26 --allowerasing`

dnf tells me:

```
Install   179 Packages
Upgrade  1614 Packages
Remove      4 Packages
Skip      746 Packages
```

All but 10 of the 746 skipped packages come from `fedora` repo itself, not from third parties. The other 10 come from `rpmfusion-free`. Some of the skipped packages are not important, but some are crucial, like anaconda itself! This is essentially independent of the release version I tried: 24, 25 or 26.

Obviously, this upgrade would led to a half updated and potentially very unstable system.

Why are there so many skipped packages, and how do I fix that? What about a `dnf distro-sync --allowerasing` *PRIOR* to the upgrade?

Below is the list of skipped pacakges.

Thanks!

```
 GraphicsMagick
 ImageMagick
 ImageMagick-c++
 ImageMagick-libs
 ImageMagick-perl
 LibRaw
 PackageKit-Qt5
 PyQt4
 a52dec
 abrt
 abrt-addon-ccpp
 abrt-addon-coredump-helper
 abrt-addon-kerneloops
 abrt-addon-pstoreoops
 abrt-addon-python3
 abrt-addon-vmcore
 abrt-addon-xorg
 abrt-cli
 abrt-dbus
 abrt-desktop
 abrt-gui
 abrt-gui-libs
 abrt-libs
 abrt-plugin-bodhi
 abrt-python3
 abrt-retrace-client
 abrt-tui
 anaconda
 anaconda-core
 anaconda-gui
 anaconda-tui
 anaconda-widgets
 apper
 ark
 ark-libs
 audiocd-kio
 audiocd-kio-doc
 audiocd-kio-libs
 authconfig
 avidemux
 avidemux-libs
 avidemux-qt
 bluedevil
 boost-date-time
 boost-filesystem
 boost-iostreams
 boost-system
 boost-thread
 colord-kde
 cups-filters
 cups-filters-libs
 dbusmenu-qt5
 dcraw
 device-mapper-multipath
 device-mapper-multipath-libs
 dnf
 dnf-conf
 dnf-plugins-core
 dnf-yum
 dragon
 enblend
 enchant
 ffmpeg
 ffmpeg-libs
 firefox
 firewall-config
 firewalld
 firewalld-filesystem
 foomatic
 fros
 gd
 gdk-pixbuf2
 gdk-pixbuf2-devel
 gdk-pixbuf2-modules
 gegl
 gimp
 gimp-devel
 gimp-devel-tools
 gimp-lensfun
 gimp-libs
 git
 git-core
 git-core-doc
 gnome-abrt
 gnuplot
 gnuplot-common
 gpgme
 gsl
 gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free
 gstreamer1-plugins-good
 gtkmm30
 gvfs
 gvfs-client
 gvfs-fuse
 gvfs-mtp
 harfbuzz
 harfbuzz-devel
 harfbuzz-icu
 hplip
 hplip-common
 hplip-gui
 hplip-libs
 html2ps
 hugin
 hugin-base
 hunspell
 initial-setup
 initial-setup-gui
 initscripts
 inkscape
 jasper-libs
 java-1.8.0-openjdk
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless
 javapackages-tools
 k3b
 k3b-libs
 kaccounts-integration
 kaccounts-providers
 kactivities-libs
 kactivitymanagerd
 kamera
 kamoso
 kcalc
 kcharselect
 kcm_systemd
 kcolorchooser
 kde-apps-rpm-macros
 kde-baseapps-common
 kde-cli-tools
 kde-l10n
 kde-partitionmanager
 kde-platform-plugin
 kde-print-manager
 kde-print-manager-libs
 kde-runtime
 kde-runtime-flags
 kde-runtime-libs
 kde-workspace-common
 kdecoration
 kdegraphics-thumbnailers
 kdelibs
 kdelibs-common
 kdelibs-ktexteditor
 kdelibs-webkit
 kdenlive
 kdepimlibs
 kdeplasma-addons
 kdesu
 kdialog
 kdm
 kdnssd
 keditbookmarks
 keditbookmarks-libs
 kf5-attica
 kf5-baloo
 kf5-baloo-libs
 kf5-bluez-qt
 kf5-frameworkintegration
 kf5-frameworkintegration-libs
 kf5-gpgmepp
 kf5-kactivities-libs
 kf5-kactivities-stats
 kf5-karchive
 kf5-kauth
 kf5-kbookmarks
 kf5-kcmutils
 kf5-kcodecs
 kf5-kcompletion
 kf5-kconfig-core
 kf5-kconfig-gui
 kf5-kconfigwidgets
 kf5-kcoreaddons
 kf5-kcrash
 kf5-kdbusaddons
 kf5-kdeclarative
 kf5-kded
 kf5-kdelibs4support
 kf5-kdelibs4support-libs
 kf5-kdesu
 kf5-kdewebkit
 kf5-kdnssd
 kf5-kdoctools
 kf5-kemoticons
 kf5-kfilemetadata
 kf5-kglobalaccel
 kf5-kglobalaccel-libs
 kf5-kguiaddons
 kf5-khtml
 kf5-ki18n
 kf5-kiconthemes
 kf5-kidletime
 kf5-kinit
 kf5-kio-core
 kf5-kio-core-libs
 kf5-kio-doc
 kf5-kio-file-widgets
 kf5-kio-ntlm
 kf5-kio-widgets
 kf5-kio-widgets-libs
 kf5-kitemmodels
 kf5-kitemviews
 kf5-kjobwidgets
 kf5-kjs
 kf5-kjsembed
 kf5-knewstuff
 kf5-knotifications
 kf5-knotifyconfig
 kf5-kpackage
 kf5-kparts
 kf5-kpeople
 kf5-kplotting
 kf5-kpty
 kf5-kross-core
 kf5-kross-ui
 kf5-krunner
 kf5-kservice
 kf5-ktexteditor
 kf5-ktextwidgets
 kf5-kunitconversion
 kf5-kwallet
 kf5-kwallet-libs
 kf5-kwayland
 kf5-kwidgetsaddons
 kf5-kwindowsystem
 kf5-kxmlgui
 kf5-kxmlrpcclient
 kf5-modemmanager-qt
 kf5-networkmanager-qt
 kf5-plasma
 kf5-solid
 kf5-solid-libs
 kf5-sonnet-core
 kf5-sonnet-ui
 kf5-threadweaver
 kfind
 kget
 kget-libs
 kgreeter-plugins
 khelpcenter
 khotkeys
 kinfocenter
 kio-extras
 kmahjongg
 kmenuedit
 kmines
 kolourpaint
 kolourpaint-libs
 konqueror
 konqueror-libs
 konsole5
 konsole5-part
 konversation
 kpartx
 kpat
 krdc
 krdc-libs
 krfb
 krfb-libs
 kruler
 krusader
 kscd
 kscreen
 kscreenlocker
 ksshaskpass
 ksysguard
 ksysguardd
 ktorrent
 ktorrent-libs
 ktp-accounts-kcm
 ktp-approver
 ktp-auth-handler
 ktp-common-internals
 ktp-contact-list
 ktp-desktop-applets
 ktp-filetransfer-handler
 ktp-kded-integration-module
 ktp-send-file
 ktp-text-ui
 kwalletmanager
 kwalletmanager5
 kwayland-integration
 kwebkitpart
 kwin
 kwin-common
 kwin-libs
 kwrite
 kwrited
 langtable
 langtable-data
 langtable-python
 langtable-python3
 lensfun
 lensfun-devel
 lensfun-tools
 libGLEW
 libaccounts-qt5
 libavdevice
 libblockdev
 libblockdev-btrfs
 libblockdev-crypto
 libblockdev-dm
 libblockdev-kbd
 libblockdev-loop
 libblockdev-lvm
 libblockdev-mdraid
 libblockdev-mpath
 libblockdev-plugins-all
 libblockdev-swap
 libblockdev-utils
 libbluray
 libcmis
 libe-book
 libgit2
 libgltf
 libical
 libicu
 libicu-devel
 libipa_hbac
 libkcddb
 libkcddb-doc
 libkcompactdisc
 libkdegames
 libkdegames4
 libkgapi
 libkolabxml
 libksane
 libkscreen-qt5
 libksysguard
 libksysguard-common
 libkworkspace
 libkworkspace5
 libopenraw
 liborcus
 libpwquality
 libqalculate
 libreoffice-calc
 libreoffice-core
 libreoffice-impress
 libreoffice-opensymbol-fonts
 libreoffice-pyuno
 libreoffice-ure
 libreoffice-writer
 libreport
 libreport-anaconda
 libreport-cli
 libreport-fedora
 libreport-filesystem
 libreport-gtk
 libreport-plugin-bugzilla
 libreport-plugin-kerneloops
 libreport-plugin-logger
 libreport-plugin-reportuploader
 libreport-plugin-ureport
 libreport-python3
 libreport-web
 libsane-hpaio
 libselinux
 libselinux-python
 libselinux-python3
 libselinux-utils
 libsss_autofs
 libsss_idmap
 libsss_sudo
 libtidy
 libudisks2
 libvisio
 libvncserver
 libvpx
 libwebp
 libxml2
 livecd-tools
 lorax
 luminance-hdr
 mediawriter
 mencoder
 mlt
 mplayer
 mplayer-common
 newt
 newt-python
 newt-python3
 nss
 nss-pem
 nss-sysinit
 nss-tools
 okular
 okular-libs
 okular-part
 open-vm-tools
 open-vm-tools-desktop
 openCOLLADA
 opencv-core
 pango
 pango-devel
 perl
 perl-Algorithm-Diff
 perl-Archive-Tar
 perl-Archive-Zip
 perl-B-Lint
 perl-Business-ISBN
 perl-Business-ISBN-Data
 perl-CGI
 perl-CPAN
 perl-CPAN-Meta
 perl-CPAN-Meta-Requirements
 perl-CPAN-Meta-YAML
 perl-Carp
 perl-Class-ISA
 perl-Compress-Bzip2
 perl-Compress-Raw-Bzip2
 perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib
 perl-Convert-BinHex
 perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Bignum
 perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA
 perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Random
 perl-Crypt-SSLeay
 perl-Curses
 perl-Curses-UI
 perl-DBD-MySQL
 perl-DBI
 perl-DB_File
 perl-Data-Dumper
 perl-Data-OptList
 perl-Data-Section
 perl-Devel-Size
 perl-Digest
 perl-Digest-HMAC
 perl-Digest-MD5
 perl-Digest-SHA
 perl-Email-Date-Format
 perl-Encode
 perl-Encode-Detect
 perl-Encode-Locale
 perl-Env
 perl-Error
 perl-Exporter
 perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder
 perl-ExtUtils-Command
 perl-ExtUtils-Install
 perl-ExtUtils-MM-Utils
 perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
 perl-ExtUtils-Manifest
 perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS
 perl-File-CheckTree
 perl-File-HomeDir
 perl-File-Listing
 perl-File-Path
 perl-File-Temp
 perl-File-Which
 perl-Filter
 perl-Geo-IP
 perl-Getopt-Long
 perl-Git
 perl-HTML-Parser
 perl-HTML-Tagset
 perl-HTTP-Cookies
 perl-HTTP-Date
 perl-HTTP-Message
 perl-HTTP-Negotiate
 perl-HTTP-Tiny
 perl-IO-Compress
 perl-IO-HTML
 perl-IO-Socket-INET6
 perl-IO-Socket-IP
 perl-IO-Socket-SSL
 perl-IO-Zlib
 perl-IPC-Cmd
 perl-IPC-System-Simple
 perl-Image-ExifTool
 perl-JSON-PP
 perl-LWP-MediaTypes
 perl-Locale-Codes
 perl-Locale-Maketext
 perl-Locale-Maketext-Simple
 perl-MIME-Base64
 perl-MIME-Lite
 perl-MIME-Types
 perl-MIME-tools
 perl-MRO-Compat
 perl-Mail-DKIM
 perl-Mail-SPF
 perl-MailTools
 perl-Math-BigInt
 perl-Math-Complex
 perl-Module-Build
 perl-Module-CoreList
 perl-Module-Load
 perl-Module-Load-Conditional
 perl-Module-Metadata
 perl-Module-Pluggable
 perl-NTLM
 perl-Net-CIDR-Lite
 perl-Net-DNS
 perl-Net-HTTP
 perl-Net-SMTP-SSL
 perl-Net-SSLeay
 perl-NetAddr-IP
 perl-Package-Generator
 perl-Params-Check
 perl-Params-Util
 perl-PathTools
 perl-Perl-OSType
 perl-Pod-Checker
 perl-Pod-Escapes
 perl-Pod-LaTeX
 perl-Pod-Parser
 perl-Pod-Perldoc
 perl-Pod-Plainer
 perl-Pod-Simple
 perl-Pod-Usage
 perl-Scalar-List-Utils
 perl-Socket
 perl-Socket6
 perl-Software-License
 perl-Storable
 perl-Sub-Exporter
 perl-Sub-Install
 perl-Switch
 perl-Sys-Syslog
 perl-Term-ANSIColor
 perl-Term-Cap
 perl-TermReadKey
 perl-Test-Harness
 perl-Test-Simple
 perl-Text-Balanced
 perl-Text-Diff
 perl-Text-Glob
 perl-Text-ParseWords
 perl-Text-Soundex
 perl-Text-Tabs+Wrap
 perl-Text-Template
 perl-Text-Unidecode
 perl-Time-HiRes
 perl-Time-Local
 perl-TimeDate
 perl-Tk
 perl-URI
 perl-URI-Find
 perl-Unicode-EastAsianWidth
 perl-Unicode-Normalize
 perl-WWW-RobotRules
 perl-XML-LibXML
 perl-XML-NamespaceSupport
 perl-XML-Parser
 perl-XML-SAX
 perl-XML-SAX-Base
 perl-XML-XPath
 perl-autodie
 perl-constant
 perl-devel
 perl-encoding
 perl-inc-latest
 perl-libnet
 perl-libs
 perl-libwww-perl
 perl-local-lib
 perl-macros
 perl-open
 perl-parent
 perl-podlators
 perl-threads
 perl-threads-shared
 perl-version
 phonon-qt5
 phonon-qt5-backend-gstreamer
 picmi
 plasma-breeze
 plasma-breeze-common
 plasma-desktop
 plasma-integration
 plasma-milou
 plasma-nm
 plasma-nm-l2tp
 plasma-nm-openconnect
 plasma-nm-openswan
 plasma-nm-openvpn
 plasma-nm-pptp
 plasma-nm-vpnc
 plasma-pa
 plasma-pk-updates
 plasma-systemsettings
 plasma-user-manager
 plasma-workspace
 plasma-workspace-common
 plasma-workspace-drkonqi
 plasma-workspace-geolocation
 plasma-workspace-geolocation-libs
 plasma-workspace-libs
 policycoreutils
 polkit-kde
 polkit-qt5-1
 poppler
 poppler-glib
 poppler-qt
 poppler-qt5
 poppler-utils
 powerdevil
 pykde4
 python-pwquality
 python-qt5
 python2-blockdev
 python2-dnf
 python3
 python3-PyQt4
 python3-augeas
 python3-beaker
 python3-blivet
 python3-blockdev
 python3-cairo
 python3-chardet
 python3-coverage
 python3-cssselect
 python3-cups
 python3-dbus
 python3-decorator
 python3-dmidecode
 python3-dnf
 python3-dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
 python3-dnf-plugins-core
 python3-firewall
 python3-gobject
 python3-gobject-base
 python3-hawkey
 python3-humanize
 python3-inotify
 python3-iscsi-initiator-utils
 python3-javapackages
 python3-kickstart
 python3-libs
 python3-libxml2
 python3-lxml
 python3-mako
 python3-markupsafe
 python3-meh
 python3-meh-gui
 python3-ntplib
 python3-pid
 python3-pillow
 python3-pip
 python3-pwquality
 python3-pycurl
 python3-pyparsing
 python3-pyparted
 python3-pysocks
 python3-pytz
 python3-pyudev
 python3-reportlab
 python3-requests
 python3-requests-file
 python3-requests-ftp
 python3-setuptools
 python3-sip
 python3-slip
 python3-slip-dbus
 python3-sssdconfig
 python3-systemd
 python3-urllib3
 pyzor
 qca-qt5
 qca-qt5-ossl
 qpdf-libs
 qt5-qdbusviewer
 qt5-qtbase
 qt5-qtbase-common
 qt5-qtbase-gui
 qt5-qtconnectivity
 qt5-qtdeclarative
 qt5-qtenginio
 qt5-qtgraphicaleffects
 qt5-qtlocation
 qt5-qtmultimedia
 qt5-qtquickcontrols
 qt5-qtscript
 qt5-qtsensors
 qt5-qtserialport
 qt5-qtsvg
 qt5-qttools
 qt5-qttools-common
 qt5-qttools-libs-clucene
 qt5-qttools-libs-designer
 qt5-qttools-libs-help
 qt5-qtwebchannel
 qt5-qtwebkit
 qt5-qtwebsockets
 qt5-qtx11extras
 qt5-qtxmlpatterns
 qtwebkit
 raptor2
 sddm
 sddm-breeze
 sddm-kcm
 selinux-policy
 selinux-policy-targeted
 signon
 signon-kwallet-extension
 signon-plugin-oauth2
 signon-ui
 sip
 sos
 spamassassin
 sssd
 sssd-ad
 sssd-client
 sssd-common
 sssd-common-pac
 sssd-ipa
 sssd-krb5
 sssd-krb5-common
 sssd-ldap
 sssd-nfs-idmap
 sssd-proxy
 system-config-printer
 system-config-printer-libs
 system-config-printer-udev
 telepathy-logger-qt
 telepathy-qt5
 texlive-bibtex-bin
 texlive-dvipdfmx-bin
 texlive-dvips-bin
 texlive-gsftopk-bin
 texlive-kpathsea-bin
 texlive-luatex-bin
 texlive-makeindex-bin
 texlive-metafont-bin
 texlive-mfware-bin
 texlive-pdftex-bin
 texlive-tex-bin
 texlive-texlive.infra-bin
 texlive-xdvi-bin
 udisks2
 ufraw
 ufraw-common
 ufraw-gimp
 vigra
 vim-X11
 vim-common
 vim-enhanced
 webkitgtk
 webkitgtk3
 webkitgtk4
 webkitgtk4-jsc
 webkitgtk4-plugin-process-gtk2
 x265-libs
 xmlrpc-c
 xmlrpc-c-client
```

Comment: Could it be that they're in the same version in both ditributions ?

Comment: @daftaupe: No. For example, I have `anaconda-23.19.10-1.fc23` installed, and the one skipped is `26.21.10-1.fc26`.

Comment: from https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade, they say you have to run `sudo dnf upgrade --refresh` before, didn't you miss this step ? otherwise maybe some more fedora-specific places like the mailing list or irc might answer better

Comment: That's just to get your system updated first, which mine is. I guess I should ask in other place, as you wrote.

Comment: Somewhere above that, it should tell you *why* it's skipping those packages....

Comment: The change from YUM to DNF brought some loss: DNF does not always report why it skips packages. Sometimes you get more info with the `--best` flag, sometimes you don't. But, anyway, I found that the third party darktable was making some mess preventing lensfun update. Removing darktable solved the issue.